# How to put docstring of property into cython cdef class?

Tags: class, cython

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to embed docstrings into the properties of cdef classes. When running the usual `object.property?` or `help(object.property)` in ipython, it doesn't show the docstring as entered, but instead shows python's docstring for the type of object the property is assigned to. This is with the `embedsignature = True` directive at the top of the `.pyx` file.

The code I'm writing has many attributes that are all producing this problem, so here is the basic format that is written so far:

```
cdef class foo:

    cdef object _attr 

    def __init__(self, attr = 0):
        self._attr = attr 

    @property 
    def attr(self): 
        """
        The docstring that should be printed.
        """ 
        return self._attr 

    @attr.setter 
    def attr(self, value): 
        self._attr = value
```

I've also tried the following deprecated syntax, which states [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#properties) that docstrings can be written like so. While deprecated, this nonetheless suggests that docstrings for properties in `cdef classes` should be supported.

```
cdef class foo: 

    cdef object _attr 

    def __init__(self, attr = 0): 
        self._attr = attr 

    property attr: 
        """
        The docstring that should be printed. 
        """ 

        def __get__(self): 
            return self._attr 

        def __set__(self, value): 
            self._attr = value
```

If I run `bar = foo()` followed by `bar.attr?` or `help(bar.attr)` in ipython, the expected docstring is "The docstring that should be printed." However, it instead displays "Convert a string do a floating point number, if possible." which is the docstring python has given the float type.

I realize that an alternative solution to this problem would be to simply use a python `class` rather than a `cdef class`, but the object I'm implementing also wraps a `typedef struct` object in `C` for which I've written an extensive library of subroutines also in `C`. This rules out the possibility of a simple python `class` wrapping.

Is there a simple solution to this problem? If not, I would interpret this as an issue with the cython implementation; docstrings for user-defined objects is rather central to python.

Answer (score 2):

Cython is working and behaving *exactly the same way as Python* (for the sake of testing I duplicated your example in plain Python).

If you call `help` on the class attribute you get the doc string correctly:

> `help(foo.attr)`
>
> The docstring that should be printed.

However if you call help on the instance attribute you get information about `int`:

> `help(foo().attr)`
>
> Help on int object:
>
> class int(object)
>
> ...

**This is correct** - `foo().attr` calls the property method which returns an integer, which is what is passed to `help`. This integer has no way of knowing that it was returned from a property so it does not make sense for it to have a docstring associated with the property.